# How should I make an abstract method that can be either async or not?

Tags: typescript

I'm implementing a base class, and want to provide a way for the derived classes to handle something. However, some derived classes will want to handle async'ly, and some will not. How can I accomplish that?

My current solution ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgCWADsATZHKBAbwCgE6EAHKAewh3h2IQAsjScAogA9YOBhACWzQgH4AFDhFjJ0gJQAuBADdmE4gG5a9Jq3ZsuvEmWGjxUwgEEwAT0Kx5i2ysIaEABRYAWwkwHAAeHT0APkMjOjRXWB4+MjlVBE0A5mDQiN1iKKo4+jpoZyKSyqqAemqEADpGhEgAVwAzNuKSgF8kYAhYbgQFJTs1CqrK2oamz2V7Zoh2zsnKiTbhiG4Q+st+G3npJ0TVGlXV4AB3YAlELZ2961HvY7cRr3tVQ3P6XpxkUITH4le5gXYpQTPezvQ4+fR0aYAYSIhFYCAkhB0AGscAgiAhmCAAFZmBCXbaDdEYBjMdASEDIcoAchaJBwbQxnCZ9TkACYAOy83npc5dSa9YFiujdYoy7pAA)):

```
abstract class BaseHandler {
    protected handleException?(exception): void;
    protected handleExceptionAsync?(exception): Promise<void>;

    async handle() : Promise<void> {
        try {
               // ... stuff
        } catch (exception) {
            // ... exception stuff
            if (this.handleExceptionAsync){
                await this.handleExceptionAsync(exception);
            } else {
                this.handleException(exception);  // Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.(2722)          
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is ok to call `await` on synchronous functions, you can simply make the return type a union:

```
abstract class BaseHandler {
    protected handleException(exception): void | Promise<void>;

    async handle() : Promise<void> {
        try {
            // ... stuff
        } catch (exception) {
            // ... exception stuff
            await this.handleException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out (the hard way) that you can `await` sync functions, but they become async - meaning that the function call will return, and the function will continue to run async'ly. This is the opposite of what `await` is intended to accomplish...

Answer (score 0):

the question marks are the reason for the error, If you are going to keep them, then you just need to add `!` after `this.handleException` `!` `(exception)` By telling typescript compiler that, it is NOT undefined in that line.

following the explanation, you can do:

1. adding `!` sign

```
abstract class BaseHandler {
    protected handleException?(exception): void;
    protected handleExceptionAsync?(exception): Promise<void>;

    async handle() : Promise<void> {
        try {
               // ... stuff
        } catch (exception) {
            // ... exception stuff
            if (this.handleExceptionAsync){
                await this.handleExceptionAsync(exception);
            } else {
                this.handleException!(exception);  // Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.(2722)          
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

2. or simply delete `?` sign from the definition

```
abstract class BaseHandler {
    protected handleException(exception): void;
    protected handleExceptionAsync(exception): Promise<void>;

    async handle() : Promise<void> {
        try {
               // ... stuff
        } catch (exception) {
            // ... exception stuff
            if (this.handleExceptionAsync){
                await this.handleExceptionAsync(exception);
            } else {
                this.handleException(exception);  // Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.(2722)          
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `!` would indeed pacify the compiler. I don't want to remove the `?`, since then derived classes will have to implement `handleException`, even if they choose to implement `handleExceptionAsync` instead.

Comment: @Jonathan I see, yeah, I think the `!` can help you in this case